# Async/Await single thread/some threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, c#-7.2

I need a little rule about correct usage of await. Run this code in .net core c# 7.2:

```
static class Program
{
    static async Task<string> GetTaskAsync(int timeout)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(timeout);
        return timeout.ToString();
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.WriteLine("Should be greater than 5000");
        await Watch(NotParallel);
        Console.WriteLine("Should be less than 5000");
        await Watch(Parallel);
    }

    public static async Task Parallel()
    {
        var res1 = GetTaskAsync(2000);
        var res2 = GetTaskAsync(3000);

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + await res1 + await res2);
    }

    public static async Task NotParallel()
    {
        var res1 = await GetTaskAsync(2000);
        var res2 = await GetTaskAsync(3000);

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + res1 + res2);
    }

    private static async Task Watch(Func<Task> func) {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        await func?.Invoke();

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    }
}
```

As you all can see the behavior of two methods are different. It's easy to get wrong in practice. So i need a "thumb rule".

**Update for real men** Please, run code. And explain please why Parallel() runs faster than NonParallel().

[image: Results, for ladies.]

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: updated ........

Comment: Are you looking for something like "Only await tasks in sequence if one depends on the other"?  It's still not clear what the question is.

Comment: juharr - it seems a good explanation. Please move it into the answers

Comment: What 'rule of thumb' are you asking for? `Task` is something that may yield a result if you `await` for it. Until then, it's just an object which does nothing. In your `NonParallel` method you don't even have a second task until the first one yields, so of course these methods are totally different.

Comment: Lyosha - nice answer. Please write it into answers.

Comment: Anyway, number of people downvoiting such nice questions and suggesting to close, makes me upset and demotivates me to ask anything here in Stack Overflow. And i guess not only me.. SO goes to the garbage of non answering questions. However, not bad for juniors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While calling `GetTaskAsync` without `await`, you actually get a Task with the method to execute (that is, `GetTaskAsync`) wrapped in. But when calling `await GetTaskAsync`, execution is suspended until the method is done executing, and then you get the result.

Let me be more clear:

```
var task = GetTaskAsync(2000);
```

Here, task is of type `Task<string>`.

```
var result = await GetTaskAsync(2000);
```

Here result is of type `string`.

So to address your first interrogation: when to await your Tasks really depends on your execution flow.

Now, as to why `Parallel()` is faster, I suggest your read this [article](https://cpratt.co/async-tips-tricks/) (everything is of interest, but for your specific example, you may jump to *Tasks return "hot"*).

Now let's break it down:

> The `await` keyword serves to halt the code until the task is completed,
>   but doesn't actually start it.

In your example, `NotParallel()` will take longer because your Tasks execute sequentially, one after the other. As the article explains:

> This is due to the tasks being awaited inline.

In `Parallel()` however...

> the tasks now run in parallel. This is due to the fact that all [tasks]
>   are started before all [tasks] are subsequently awaited, again, because
>   they return hot.

### About 'hot' tasks

I suggest your read the following: [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap)

The *Task Status* section is of interest here to understand the concepts of cold and hot tasks:

> Tasks that are created by the public Task constructors are referred to as cold tasks, because they begin their life cycle in the non-scheduled Created state and are scheduled only when Start is called on these instances.
>
> All other tasks begin their life cycle in a hot state, which means that the asynchronous operations they represent have already been initiated

I invite you to read extensively about `async/await` and `Tasks`. Here are a few resources in addition to the ones I provided above:

[Asynchronous Programming in C# 5.0 part two: Whence await?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await/)

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

[Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: Nice articles linked.